# Why isn't my delete method working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Banging my head against a wall and staring at my code, insisting that it's right isn't working.

I have a simple blogging Rails 4 app that creates, reads, and updates posts just fine. But I need to put the "D" in CRUD.

My posts_controller has these methods:

```
  def create
    @post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)
    if @post.save
      redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created. Huzzah!'
    else
      render action: 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    if current_user
      redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Not permitted :(' unless current_user.id.to_i == @post.user_id.to_i
    else
      redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Not permitted :('
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @post.destroy
    redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Post was successfully destroyed. Sad face.'
  end

  def update
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    if @post.update(post_params)
      redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully updated. Hooray!'
    else
      render action: 'edit'
    end
  end
```

and my (slim) form looks has this:

```
= link_to 'Cancel', posts_path
= link_to 'Delete', @post, method: :destroy, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }
```

When I edit the post in the app, I get redirected back to to post.

Comment: Is your current_user set?  You say it's when you edit but the title of your post says delete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of things wrong with your code.

First, you need to set the `@post` variable in your `destroy` method:

```
def destroy
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  @post.destroy
  redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Post was successfully destroyed. Sad face.'
end
```

The `method` param on your `link_to` is also incorrect. It should be `delete`, not `destroy`:

```
= link_to 'Delete', @post, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }
```

(Destroy is the name of the controller method, but delete is the name of the HTTP verb that is used to route to it)